# Dominant morphisms between projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modular-arithmetic, complex-geometry, singularity-theory, birational-geometry

Suppose $f : X\to Y$ is a finite surjective morphism of projective integral complex varieties, and let $g : X'\to X$ and $h : Y'\to Y$ be surjective **birational** morphisms from smooth projective irreducible varieties $X'$ and $Y'$.

Suppose there is a morphism $f' : X'\to Y'$ making the diagram commute, i.e. such that $h \circ f' = f\circ g$ as maps $X'\to Y$.

> Is $f'$ dominant? (hence surjective)

For more context, I have a diagram as in the question where $g,h$ are resolutions of singularities, but I have no control on how the regular locus of $X$ and $Y$ are related, so it is unclear if one can produce open subsets in $X'$ and $Y'$ such that $f'$ restricts to a surjection between the two, although I'd think irreducibility of all the four varieties should be key. I must be missing something simple.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thanks! I've added a bit of context too.

Comment: Do you mean $h\circ f'=f\circ g$ as rational morphisms $X'\dashrightarrow Y$?

Comment: @KentaS All maps are honest morphisms. The question only asks if $f'$, as a morphism $X'\to Y'$, is surjective. $g$ and $h$ are honest morphisms and they induce isomorphisms between dense opens on source and target. My guess is that one should use irreducibility to produce an open $U\subset X'$, an open $V\subset Y'$, such that $f(U)\subset V$, and $f$ is surjective from $U$ to $V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open subset $U\subset X$ such that $g\colon g^{-1}(U)\to U$ is an isomorphism, and there is an open subset $V\subset Y$ such that $h\colon h^{-1}V\to V$ is an isomorphism. Now there is a commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} g^{-1}(U\cap f^{-1}(V))=g^{-1}(U)\cap f'^{-1}(h^{-1}(V)) @>{f'}>> h^{-1}(V)\\ @V{g}VV @V{h}VV
\\ U\cap f^{-1}(V) @>{f}>> V, \end{CD}$$
where the vertical maps are isomorphisms. Since $f$ is dominant, $f(U\cap f^{-1}(V))$ is dense in $X$. Thus the image $g^{-1}(U)\cap f'^{-1}(h^{-1}(V))$ under $f'$ is dense, and so $f'$ is dominant.

Comment: Thank you! This is roughly what I was trying to do. I'm a little new to it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of a slightly different flavour: As all varieties are projective, all the maps are closed. Now suppose $f'$ is not dominant, then its image $Z = f'(X')$ is a closed subvariety of $Y'$, hence $\dim Z < \dim Y'$. As $Y' \to Y$ is birational, both have  the same dimension, so also $\dim h(Z) < \dim Y$, which means for the total image $(h \circ f')(X') = (f \circ g)(X') \neq Y$. But that contradicts the dominance and closedness of the maps $f$ and $g$, which requires that $(f \circ g)(X') = f(X) = Y$.